# Vintage Campagnolo hood

Tags: brakes, campagnolo, brake-levers

I'm looking for a Campagnolo hood like the one in the photos below. Will the newer [ErgoPower hoods](http://www.wiggle.com/campagnolo-ergopower-replacement-hoods/) fit? If not, what should I do?

[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Google [old campy](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=old+campy) for a bunch of links. The top link [http://www.campyoldy.co.uk/](http://www.campyoldy.co.uk/) helped a friend.

Comment: Your LBS should be able to source something compatible from QBP (you may have to take it to a shop which has carried Campagnolo for a while to get it though). I don't think the new Ergopower hoods are compatible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a perfect replacement on eBay: http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=321463814720